# Custom component not showing in Ionic v4 + Angular 6

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular6, custom-component, ionic4

I'm trying to add a custom component to my Ionic v4 webapp. I think I'm missing something but I don't know what. The console shows no errors, but the component it's like never used (I also tried some log inside component's .ts and it's never printed on console). Here's the code :

in *app/components/custom-component/custom-component.component.html*

```
<p>
  my custom-component works!
</p>
```

in *app/components/custom-component/custom-component.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-component',
  templateUrl: './custom-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-component.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CustomComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

in *app/components/components.module.ts*

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomComponentComponent } from './custom-component/custom-component.component';

@NgModule({
  imports : [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProgressBarComponent,
    CustomComponentComponent],
    exports: [CustomComponentComponent, ProgressBarComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Then i use the custom component in my Home page like this :

in *app/home/home.module.ts*

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: HomePage }]),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

and in *app/home/home.page.html*

```
<ion-content>
--> <app-custom-component></app-custom-component> <--
</ion-content>
```

I launch the application with *ionic serve* command, and that's the result

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, no errors in console but component content not showing. What am i missing? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user jjdev at [forum.ionicframework.com](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-component-not-showing-in-ionic-v4-angular-6/148051/8)

> Try including CustomComponentComponent in the ‘entryComponents’ array in the ComponentsModule

That solved the problem. Thanks to ionicframework community